# Почему я не могу использовать выражение(expresssion) в качестве параметра функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, expressions

Прочитав [эту](http://jsflow.org/docs/operators-expressions-statements/) статью, я вроде бы как поняла разницу между инструкцией и выражением.

1. Инструкция(statement) описывает какой-то набор действий, который необходимо выполнить.
2. Выражение(expression) - это фрагмент кода любой длины, который в ходе своего выполнения, приводит к вычислению и возврату некоторого одного значения.

Дальше [здесь](http://jsflow.org/docs/operators-expressions-statements/#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20Javascript%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.) говорится, что...

> Выражение может находится везде, где Javascript ожидает какое-то значение. Например, выражение может выступать в качестве параметра функции.

Хорошо. Почему тогда если `let a = 5` является выражением, я не могу его использовать в качестве параметра функции? Какие здесь еще есть правила, о которых я не знаю?

```js
console.log(let a = 5); //SyntaxError
```

Comment: `console.log(a = 5);`

Comment: Согласно определениям в первой статье, `a = 5` - это выражение, а `let a = 5` (включает в себя объявление переменной) - это уже инструкция

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `let a = 5` - это выражение?

Comment: @Regent да, вы правы. Но у меня возник еще вопрос... если функция - это инструкция, то как она может передаваться в другую функцию в качестве параметра (коллбэк ф-ция)? Видимо, функции в этом случае просто явл. исключением из того правила, что инструкции не могут использоваться как параметр, я так понимаю?

Comment: @Eva, не надо смешивать все в одну кучу. Есть function declaration и function expression, то что передается в качестве callback - это function expression, который входит в AssignmentExpression и, следовательно, может передаваться в качестве параметра

Comment: @Grundy хорошо. А вообще... callback функция стает function expression потому что она присваивается в качестве значения аргументу функции высшего порядка? [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/1zmo2wn8/)

Comment: @Grundy Спрашиваю, потому что [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/04a6gmrx/) нет присвоения аргументу функции высшего порядка callback функции. И что, неужели такая callback функция `func` тоже будет считаться function expression?

Comment: @Eva, не понял чем эти два примера отличаются. Надо просто рассматривать с другой стороны. Представь что ты интерпретатор js, у тебя есть набор правил что за чем может идти. Так, увидев что сейчас идет разбор функции и конкретно разбор аргументов функции, получаешь правило, что должно идти `AssignmentExpression` - если `AssignmentExpression` может быть одним выражением из списка если пройти вглубь для каждого варианта, увидим, что текущий разбираемый кусок соответствует function expression.

Comment: @Grundy то есть я понимаю, что `AssignmentExpression` - это такой список, в котором хранится все, что может быть использовано как параметр функции. И потом, все, что из этого списка используется, становится выражением. Отсюда и `function expression` - функция, которая была использована как параметр функции,  правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130136/discussion-between-grundy-and-eva).

Answer (score 1):

`let a = 5` - является [LexicalDeclaration](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LexicalDeclaration)

В то время, как [аргументы функции](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-Arguments) представляют из себя список из [AssignmentExpression](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression)

Таким образом данный кусок кода нельзя использовать в качестве параметра при  вызове функции.